# Trying to activate android back button from webview within a fragment

Tags: android, webview, fragment

**I'm trying to get the back button to work here from a webview within a fragment. The code does not compile can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?**

I'm getting the "webview is accessed from within inner class needs to be final" error.

Also I'm getting "cannot resolve symbol handler" error.

package info.androidhive.slidingmenu;

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class PagesFragment extends Fragment {

    public PagesFragment(){}



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pages, container, false);

        WebView webView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webviewpages);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        webView.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener(){

            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webView.canGoBack()) {
                    handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }

        });

        return rootView;


    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

> webview is accessed from within inner class needs to be final

`webview` variable needs to be final to be accessible from inner class. Simply declare it:

```
final WebView webView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webviewpages);
```

> cannot resolve symbol handler

There is no symbol called `handler` in the current scope but it is used from:

```
handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
```

You need to declare that symbol.

If you ask such questions, I guess you are following some tutorial. Check that tutorial again, you missed something.